# Getting error while runing simple node js app in openshift online

Tags: openshift, openshift-online

I am trying to setup node js application using one of github helloworld application code. 
I am always getting this error

[image]

Regards,
Vivek Chauhan

Comment: can you share the dockerfile that you are using ? and also repo link if it is open-source..

Answer (score 0):

From the error, seems like the package.json file doesn't have "start" script for `npm start` to work